# jQuery not working after login drupal 8 site

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, frontend

except this -
jQuery('.filter_btn').click(function() {
            jQuery('.course__filter').toggle('fast');

```
        // Course Filter Toggle
        jQuery('.views-exposed-form.course__filter fieldset legend span.fieldset-legend').click(function() {
            jQuery(this).parents('.views-exposed-form.course__filter fieldset').find('.fieldset-wrapper').slideToggle();
            jQuery(this).parents('.views-exposed-form.course__filter fieldset').find('legend span.fieldset-legend').toggleClass('icon__');
        });
    });

    // Clear All Filter Button Reload
    jQuery('.views-exposed-form.course__filter form .form-actions').wrapInner('<a href="#">Clear All</a>');
    jQuery('.views-exposed-form.course__filter form .form-actions>a').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });

    jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
        if (!jQuery(event.target).closest(".course__filter,.filter_btn").length) {
            jQuery("body").find(".course__filter").hide("fast");
        }
    });
```

all js working

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem. Can you make real sentences 

Comment: I am trying to say whenever I am logged in to the site this jquery stop working and if I am logged out it works I don't think this is something to do with drupal.